# if possible set foreign key to null when not match with any reference

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm downloading data and saving in two tables, **table_1** and **table_2**, these tables have a relationship one to many:

- table_1 columns: id, name
- table_2 columns: id table_1_id, col1, col2

I cannot control which table will be receive an insert first. For example if I get data to **table_2**, some entries still don't exist in **table_1**. Then I receive an error

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

In **table_2** I setted **table_1_id** default value NULL, but still fail.

Is it possible set to NULL **table_1_id**  when doesn't match with any row in **table_1**?

I'm using Laravel 5.5 with MySQL

Comment: you can use SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; before inserting data

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

When SQL failes to do an insert due to some error, it properly throws appropriate exceptions, as in .NET's Entity Framework connections, it throws some implementations of the SQLException. Thus if you want to insert null if the insert is failed due to FK constraint, then you can catch the appropriate exception thrown by SQL with the constraint name and then do the necessary.

In your case, create the constraint with a name. And in the code when the insert fails, try catching the exception and see the name. Then try altering the entry by replacing it with null and again try inserting and see it gets inserted.

Whatever technology you might be using, SQL excpetion handling will be present.